# Calculating Business Days in Excel/Indirect Reference

Tags: excel, date, schedule, excel-indirect

I'm working on making a spreadsheet where someone can put in a date they want a final product by, and then it will automatically fill out deadlines for different steps along the way. (i.e.) If you want something by June 22, Step C would need to be done x business days prior, Step B would need to be done y business days prior to that, and Step A z business days prior to that.

This definitely isn't the best way to do it but I think it should be okay for now because this is only needed for a finite time, I wrote out a list of all the business days in the relevant time frame. I want to make it so when someone types in the day they need the final product, the dates before it fill out just by inputting the cell x cells before the final date, etc.

If there's a better/easier way to do this I'm all ears. This is just what I was thinking as someone with not all that much Excel experience who just needs to make this functional, not perfect.

Comment: Some test data and expected outcome would help visualize your text.